# TypeError on pandas webreader

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get stock date using the web datareader library and i am receiving an error i have never gotten before even thought i have not changed anything

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = date(2010,10,1)
end = datetime.now()

df = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', start, end)
print(df)
```

The full error i receive reads as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\code\newgen\newmain.py", line 60, in <module>
    df = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', start, end)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 379, in DataReader
    ).read()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 253, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
    data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked for me was downgrading the webreader package to 0.9.0 and then using yfinance to hijack it as such

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

# download dataframe
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```